# how to solve configuration files are not serializable

Tags: laravel

I run php artisan config:cache On my terminal I got the message 'configuration cache cleared" but aloso a LogicalExpectation

```
Configuration cache cleared!

LogicException

Your configuration files are not serializable.

at C:\xampp\htdocs\Pharmacy-management-system\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ConfigCacheCommand.php:71 
67▕ require $configPath; 
68▕ } catch (Throwable $e) { 
69▕ $this->files->delete($configPath); 
70▕ ➜ 
71▕ throw new LogicException('Your configuration files are not serializable.', 0, $e); 
72▕ } 
73▕ 
74▕ $this->info('Configuration cached successfully!'); 75▕ }

1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Pharmacy-management-system\bootstrap\cache\config.php:173 Error::("Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state()")

2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Pharmacy-management-system\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ConfigCacheCommand.php:67 require()
```

How to fix this problem , thank you .

I deleted the vendor folder and reinstall the composer but nothing changed .

Comment: well have you checked the configuration files and checked that they are correctly formatted ? one of them must have broken php

Answer (score 0):

Open the file mentioned in the error message: C:\xampp\htdocs\Pharmacy-management-system\bootstrap\cache\config.php. Look for the line number specified in the error (in this case, line 173) is this file exist?

If yes then your closure option looks like this

```
'key' => function() {
    // Closure logic
},
```

Keep in mind that configuration caching is optional, and for development environments, it might be more convenient to disable it. In your `.env` file, set `CONFIG_CACHE` to `false`:

CONFIG_CACHE=false

After making the changes, run `php artisan config:cache` again to rebuild the configuration cache.